# ROS personal global planner - undefined symbol: _ZN18base_local_planner12CostmapModelC1ERKN10costmap_2d9Costmap2DE

Tags: c++, ros

My setup is: ROS melodic, Ubuntu: 18.04

I want simulate turtlebot3 moving with my own global planner and have been following this tutorial to get started: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS#Running_the_Plugin_on_the_Turtlebot. The tutorial seem to be made for ROS hydro, but as it was the best source of guidance I could find I hoped it would work. I have been using this turtlebot3 tutorial and commands to get started: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/nav_simulation/

There is no problem having the robot navigate with 2D Nav Goal in rviz using the in-built planning packages, but when I try to run the the global path planner in my own package I get the following error when I try to launch the 'turtlebot3_navigation.launch' file:

```
[ INFO] [1661178206.728674676, 7.359000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1661178206.742733426, 7.372000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1661178206.945370142, 7.575000000]: Resizing costmap to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1661178207.047423541, 7.676000000]: Received a 384 X 384 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1661178207.053220010, 7.678000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1661178207.056864268, 7.685000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: scan
[ INFO] [1661178207.079615282, 7.706000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base: symbol lookup error: /home/aut/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libmy_global_planner_lib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN18base_local_planner12CostmapModelC1ERKN10costmap_2d9Costmap2DE
[move_base-4] process has died [pid 625, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=/cmd_vel odom:=odom __name:=move_base __log:=/home/aut/.ros/log/f4c41f78-2225-11ed-befb-b8ca3a965376/move_base-4.log].
log file: /home/aut/.ros/log/f4c41f78-2225-11ed-befb-b8ca3a965376/move_base-4*.log
```

I ran c++filt on the symbol lookup error and got:

```
c++filt _ZN18base_local_planner12CostmapModelC1ERKN10costmap_2d9Costmap2DE
base_local_planner::CostmapModel::CostmapModel(costmap_2d::Costmap2D const&)
```

I've beeen using this code (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/carrot_planner/src/carrot_planner.cpp) and (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/carrot_planner/include/carrot_planner/carrot_planner.h) changing carrot_planner and CarrotPlanner to my_global_planner and MyGlobalPlanner, figuring that using some code is already/should already be working was a good way to avoid confusion about whether my code or something else caused errors.

My CMakeList.txt is looking like this currently:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(my_global_planner)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED
  actionlib
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES my_global_planner
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS other_catkin_pkg
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(my_global_planner_lib src/my_global_planner/my_global_planner.cpp)
```

I've been experimenting with it, adding stuff like:
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
COMPONENTS
angles
base_local_planner
costmap_2d
nav_core
pluginlib
roscpp
tf2
tf2_geometry_msgs
tf2_ros
)

and such in the catkin_packages also, but it doesn't seem to have worked and I've returned it to how it was. I've also tried adding more than just:

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

<build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>
<exec_depend>nav_core</exec_depend>
```

to my package.xml, but no luck there either.

I hope I've made the problem clear and provided the needed information without dumping a massive sheet of code here. I feel that I've exhausted all my options at this point and any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what the error shows, your file has found the corrected header file, however, when looking up the lib, there is no correlated lib file.

There could be many reasons for that, e,g

You have multiple incompatible versions of costmap2D, to solve it, just delete all cost map in both workspace and in /opt/ros.  then reinstall the costmap2d with corrected branch https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/melodic-devel

Secondly, In your cmakelist, do include costmap_2d and navigation inside find_package

Also include  costmap_2d and navigation in your manifest